# Which software tool is used to make three dimensional graphics shown in the following photo?

Tags: 3d

After visiting the website form the the WOLF corporation, I could watch such graphics with breathtaking view. May I ask please how to make such graphics? 
[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  There's no way to tell which 3D software was used. It could be literally any one of them.  There's Blender (which is free and Open Source), and paid software such as Cinema 4D, Maya, 3ds Max, etc.  If you want tutorials for how to make 3D models and scenes, there are tutorials on youtube. There's [a good one here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UWyER_hax_A&feature=emb_logo) for Blender.

Comment: Yup - I’ve done this kind of interior iso-section view in Modo, blender, and SketchUp, and have also done ‘em directly in architectural BIM modelling tools like ArchiCAD and Revit - you can even do ‘em in MagicaVoxel if you’ve the patience of a dragon...

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to get a home- or interior planning program, a "floor planner". There you can build rooms and walls and place 3D models of nearly everything usual stuff like carpets, furnitures, catering equipment, kitchen tools, faucets, doors, windows, lights etc... Everything is freely movable, the colors are selectable and the camera view is freely adjustable. Programs regularly have a big selection of ready to use 3D models.

There's numerous options available, also freeware and limited free versions.

A good option is to get a general 3D modeller. SketchUP can be recommended also for this purpose due its simplicity and its vast library of ready to use models in their 3D Warehouse.

This is one randomly selected but typical snippet of a floor planning software ad. I do not claim anything of its value when compared to others:

[image]

Then there's one possibility to get all for free: Check what's available from big global furniture marketing companies. I've seen at least one which has in their website a scene building application. Do not expect they allow you to sell or otherwise distribute the generated model or image.